# ID3 Implementation Clarification

Tags: id3

I am trying to implement the ID3 algorithm, and am looking at the pseudo-code:

[image]

([Source](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr07/cos424/papers/mitchell-dectrees.pdf))

I am confused by the bit where it says:

If examples_vi is empty, create a leaf node with label = most common value in TargegetAttribute in Examples.

Unless I am missing out on something, shouldn't this be the most common class?

That is, if we cannot split the data on an attribute value because no sample takes that value for the particular attribute, then we take the most common class among all samples and use that?

Also, isn't this just as good as picking a random class?

The training set tells us nothing about the relation between the attribute value and the class labels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Unless I am missing out on something, shouldn't this be the most
>   common class?

You're correct, and the text also says the same. Look at the function description at the top :

```
Target_Attribute is the attribute whose value is to be predicted by the tree
```

so the value of Target_Attribute **is** the class/label.

> 2) That is, if we cannot split the data on an attribute value because no sample takes that value for the particular attribute, then we take the most common class among all samples and use that?

Yes, but not among **all** samples in your **whole** dataset, but rather those samples that reached up to this point in the tree/recursion. (ID3 functions is recursive and so the current `Examples` is actually `Examples_vi` of the caller)

> 3) Also, isn't this just as good as picking a random class?
>   The training set tells us nothing about the relation between the attribute value and the class labels...

No, picking a random class (with equal chances for each class) is not the same. Because often the inputs do have an unbalanced class distribution (this distribution is often called *the prior distribution* in many texts), so you may have 99% of examples are positive and only 1% negative. So whenever you really have no information whatsoever to decide on the outcome of some input, it makes sense to predict the most probable class, so that you have the most probability of being correct. This maximizes your classifier's accuracy on unseen data only under the assumption that the class distribution in your training data is the same as in the unseen data.

This explanation holds with the same reasoning for the base case when `Attributes` is empty (see 4 line in your pseudocode text); whenever we have no information, we just report the most common class of the data at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you never implemented the codes(ID3) but still want to know more in processing details, I suggest you to read this paper:
[Building Decision Trees in Python](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/python/2006/02/09/ai_decision_trees.html?page=1)
and here is the source code from the paper:
[decision tree source code](http://archive.oreilly.com/python/2006/02/09/examples/dtree.tar.gz)
This paper has a example or use example from your book(replace the "data" file with the same format). And you can just debug it (with some breakpoints) in eclipse to check the attribute values during the algorithms running. 
Go over it, you will understand ID3 better.